# What function is used to graph the potential curve of two hydrogens with parallel spins?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, reference-request

**TL; DR**

I am asking for

- an analytic potential curve function for the triplet state of $\ce{H2}$ (preferred) with experimental parameters, or
- experimental data (enough points to realise a smooth-looking curve).

Also see solid red curve pictured below.

---

To characterise the energy of a two-atom system, [Morse potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_potential) is applied as a second approximation after the harmonic oscillator model. This is an analytic function of the form $$E=D_\mathrm{e}\left\{1-\exp[-a(r-r_\mathrm{c})]\right\}$$

where the parameters $D_e$, $a$ and $r_c$ depend on the atoms in play. Surely enough, better results are achievable. For examples on simple molecules, I found the paper by Hulburt and Hirschfelder, 'Potential Energy Functions for Diatomic Molecules', *J. Phys. Chem.*, ($1940$) to be rather useful. Have a look at [equations $(14)$ and ($15$)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1750827) specifically (available more easily [here](https://sites.chem.colostate.edu/diverdi/C475/experiments/quantum_computation_methods/references/j_chem_phys_1941_v9_p61.pdf)). The one I used was

> $$E_{\mathrm{P}}=\mathrm{D_e}[(1-\mathrm{e}^{-z})^2+\mathrm{c}x^3\mathrm{e}^{-2z}(1+\mathrm{b}z)],$$
>
> where
>
> $$z=\frac{\omega_\mathrm{e}}{{2}\sqrt{\mathrm{B_eD_e}}}\left(\frac{x-\mathrm{r_0}}{\mathrm{r_0}}\right)$$

This is for the case where spins are antiparallel.

If atoms of parallel spin approach one another, the qualitative picture is quite different. A smaller distance will equal higher energy regardless of separation, *i.e.,* no stable equilibrium state exists. Unfortunately, finding a nice function for the antibonding situation proved less fruitful. An example of what I'm after is the solid red curve found in [this Wolfram demonstration](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ValenceBondTheoryOfTheHydrogenMolecule/).

[image: Neutral triplet state of a dihydrogen failing to form, Wolfram demonstrations, http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ValenceBondTheoryOfTheHydrogenMolecule/]

Comment: I did contact a representative of Wolfram Research Europe, but (for some reason) failed to receive an answer. Furthermore, I was initally reluctant to post this question due to the fact that it is essentially a data question... but here it is anyway. If it's off-topic, closing will not offend.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that you wont be able to find a closed analytic expression for $\mathrm{H_2}$, since no closed analytic expresion is possible for a many-body problem (more than 2 bodies). That said you can calculate as many points on the triplet curve as you like by using a QM program able of doing unrestricted Hartree-Fock (UHF). Here you should be aware that UHF does not give very good potential curves, because the Hartree-Fock approximation lacks the electron correleation energy. $\mathrm{H_2}$ is a quite small system, so you will be able to make a potential curve using unrestricted MP2 or unrectriced CCSD. I do believe that PySCF is capable of doing such calculations. Regarding the experimental data, I am not aware of any databases for such kind of data. I would suggest finding a paper where a curve is presented and then use engauge digitizer to extract the points you need.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! Apologies for the delay, I was swamped. Didn't even think of the engauge digitiser approach. Will give it a go in the coming days, and depending on the outcome (probably) will accept the answer :).

Answer (score 1):

Potentiology is a field that began in the early days of quantum mechanics:

- 1924: John Lennard-Jones publishes the Lennard-Jones pontial
- 1929: Philip M. Morse publishes the Morse potenital.

The most recent reference you gave was a potential from:

- 1940: by Hugh Hulburt and Joseph Hirschfelder

You seem to be hoping that in the last 80 years, someone might have come up with something better. 

 The answer is the 2009 [Morse/Long-range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse/Long-range_potential), which is the most flexible potential energy function known. It has the theoretically correct long-range behaviour built into it. You can easily do the anti-bonding potential, and also double-well potentials, potentials with a shelf, potentials with a shoulder, potentials with a barrier, etc.